# In Java can changing the value in a map

Tags: java, dictionary

In java can you change the value of a map to be a string,double, or int. For example, if all my key's are names, but my values can be numbers,names, or a decimal. A output would be something like this(bold is user input)

```
Greg marley
Mandy 12
John  1.8

**{Greg=marley, Mandy=12, John=1.8}**
```

Comment: He has not even asked anything! Yet so many answers. Lolz

Answer (score 1):

Possible. Use

```
Map<String,Object>
```

But are you sure you are using this in a right way?

Answer (score 0):

Your `Map` declaration should be:

```
Map<String, Object>
```

**Example Code:**

```
Map<String, Object> map=new HashMap<>();
map.put("Greg","marley");
map.put("Mandy",12);
map.put("John",1.8);
System.out.println(map);
```

**Output:**

```
{Mandy=12, John=1.8, Greg=marley}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<String, Object> mapName = new HashMap<>();
```

> Key- String
>
> Value- `Object` type

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can ,

As the key and value both have to be Objects not primitive,

String is Obvious and Other primitives i.e int, double are Wrapped to their corresponding Wrappers ie. Integer, Double

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

If you are using JDK 1.5 and above

```
Map<String, Object> map;
```

But for JDK 1.4 and other

```
Map map;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can still use `Map<String, String>`.

Store int/decimal value as String and parse it back to specific type.

Answer (score 0):

Use Map , in which key is String and value is type of object.. so that cast..

```
 Map<String, Object>
```

Later you can iterate the map.. If want to print..